# Apache camel regex pattern for txt files

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I would like to use apache camel with regex pattern for txt files, but the problem is the correct pattern and how to use it in `from()` method. The documentation mentions only about the keyword include and exclude. Which is the easiest way to use a pattern in order to check if filename matches the regex pattern? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest might be the one you've mentioned (`include` parameter on the file endpoint). Example (include every txt):

```
from("file://input/directory?include=.*\\.txt")
```

Other option is to implement a [GenericFileFilter](http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/file2.html#File2-Usingfilter).

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only checking for the file name, you can do something like this for files appearing in a specific folder and choose what to do with them using a predicate:

```
from("file://fooFileFolder/")
    .choice()
        .when(header("CamelFileNameOnly").regex("fooPattern")).to("mock:fooHere")
        .otherwise().to("mock:fooThere")
    .end();
```

It's up to you to use the regex suitable for the matching pattern in the currently read file name you're looking to apply the test to.  You can also use regex with Camel's Simple dialect.